# Arangodb insert multiple rows and using UPSERT

Tags: arangodb, aql

how do i insert multiple rows in arangodb with UPSERT?
Collection contains a unique index which prevent insert duplicate documents.
multiple insert work fine without unique index, but how can i handle update/replace  in multiple insert with unique index?

like this:

```
INSERT [{doc1},{doc2},{doc3}]
IN collection

UPDATE {} // when duplicate per document
```

---

**Update 1**

SQL look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table(name, value)
VALUES('a', '1'), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=`value`
```

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using UPSERT as described in the ArangoDB documentation? Is there any specific problem? Can you add more details about what kind of query did you use and what error do you get?

Comment: No problem if i use single row insert, i'm try to use UPSERT with multiple rows insert.
as sample code in question, if i use sql it may look like this:
`
INSERT INTO table(name, value)
VALUES('a', '1'), ('b', 2), ('c', 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name="value"
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ArangoDB supports UPSERT operation:  https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/upsert/

From ArangoDB documentation:

> When using the UPDATE variant of the upsert operation, the found document will be partially updated, meaning only the attributes specified in updateExpression will be updated or added. When using the REPLACE variant of upsert, existing documents will be replaced with the contexts of updateExpression.

You can use UPSERT to update/replace/insert multiple records as following:

Let's insert few sample documents into your `collection` with the unique hash index for `name` attribute first:

```
FOR doc in [
    { "name": "Doc 1", "value": 1 }, 
    { "name": "Doc 2", "value": 1 }, 
    { "name": "Doc 3", "value": 1 }]

INSERT doc IN collection
```

Now if you want to perform a batch upsert you can run the following AQL:

```
FOR doc in [
    { "name": "Doc 2", "value": 2 }, 
    { "name": "Doc 3", "value": 2 },
    { "name": "Doc 4", "value": 1 }
]

UPSERT { "name": doc.name }

INSERT doc

UPDATE { "value": doc.value } in collection
```

AQL query above inserts one new `Doc 4` document and updates value attribute for the `Doc 2` and `Doc 3`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, arangodb upsert documnet is about single row insert.
if i try to batch insert so have to repeat upsert on each insert `UPSERT{} INSERT{} UPDATE{}`, in ordert to prevent multiple calling upsert i have to batch insert.

Comment: Batch processing is also possible with UPSERT. Please check my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks **Peter**, this is the right way to achieve my desired result.